# Hit django API present on centos6 using postman on windows

Tags: python, django, windows, postman, centos6

I have my django project on centos6 machine which i run using putty with help of ssh key and i have postman on my windows. I want to configure django project so that when i run 'python manage.py runserver` on centos6, postman on windows should be able to send data to django server.

let's say my centos6 machine ip is `XX.XX.XX.XX` then should i use `http://XX.XX.XX.XX:22` as an address in postman to send data or what changes should i need to make in my django project settings.py file.

what should i do?

Comment: Try
`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`
and at postman `http://10.12.13.130:8000`

Comment: You can use `$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` and than on your windows machine call api at `http://10.12.13.130:22:8000` Note: This is only for development purpose if you wanted to run on production configure Django with Nginx or Apache.

Comment: `File "manage.py", line 14
    ) from exc`     getting this syntax error

Comment: ok, i fixed above one, it seems like it was due to virtualenv,  I am getting `couldn't get any response` in postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running "iptables -L". It will show you all the rules of kernel firewall. Flush the rules, using "iptables -F" and then run the server as "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000".

Also run postman as "http://10.12.13.130:8000/your-url".

It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

When running it from centos, it said permission denied when tring to do this:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

Since it was a permission issue the following worked just fine.

```
sudo /path/to/your/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

NOTE: that you are running a server on port 80, which is a HTTP Port. So when typing the URL from your web-browser you do not necessarily need to type ":80" in your URL.

```
http://10.12.13.130:80/
```

The following should suffice. Even if you do type ":80" it is considered the same.

```
http://10.12.13.130:8000/
```

However for other port numbers such as 8080 etc, :8080 is required to be part of the URL.